# DBus error when accessing FTP from Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, ftp

I always get this error when I click on a FTP bookmark in Nautilus:

"DBus error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Mountpoint Already registered"

When I click a second time it works (not always). This is annoying and makes working with FTP servers no fun. Is there any work-around for this problem?

Comment: Please consider filing a bug report as described at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs .

Comment: I sometimes get this error too but more often in Samba-shares. They are always mounted anyways. Not serious but rather weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this ? 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/699840

Comment: On launchpad on the URL you specified, I filed a comment on a workaround for this bug. It's not perfect, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this:

Double click your FTP bookmark, if you have created one. And the error will appear.

Click the "Browse Network" under the active connection that you just tried to connect to.

When you are inside "Browse Network" click on the active connection, that you tried earlier "FTP as xxx".

After this you should be able to connect to the FTP.